# MSSQL- Select users whose time is 10:00 AM in their respective country/region/timezone?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timezone

I am trying to run a scheduler which needs to select all those users whose morning time is 10:00 AM in their timezone. I got user's countries in my database and my scheduler will send email to the user at 10 AM of their location.

Comment: Run half-hourly (thanks India) and compare users' time differences to server time...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are millions of users. We only want to pick those users who are having morning time. We don't have user's time. We just have Country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saving country for user will not solve your problem. As some countries have multiple time zones like us and canada.

Comment: Although it is not something a solution but a good hint. You are right Deepak. I have to do have more in my database to fix my issue. I created a system which will add exact or central timezone for each country. I also gave user an option to edit his/her profile and to choose exact timezone once user is registered and  logged in. 

So having user's timezone gives me flexibility to loop through and find those countries which going through morning session of time.

Comment: Yes. Its good to save user timezone in database. Also in some countries there are multiple time zone e.g canada has Pacific, Central, Atlantic and so on. so it will be good if you save Distinct timezone offset in seprate table and just monitor time for those timezone. This will solve your issue if you have user from same country but having different timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you have the country, you can roughly estimate the timezone and the corresponding time difference (offset from UTC). Of course, this won't account for daylight savings times (yay).

```
Country   | Offset
UK        | 0:00
France    | 1:00
India     | 5:30
USA(E)    | -5:00
USA(C)    | -6:00
```

You can then use this offset to select your users

Comment: More or less the same solution as you suggested I adapted. Instead of having offset, i saved timezone which facilitate me to use TimezoneInfo class of c# to get the offset. Thanks for your response.